# MVC 3 refresh changes made to page doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am starting to learn MVC 3 (Razor engine) and I am having difficulty understanding why my changes don't get applied to page. Basically I have done this: I have imported my DAL and model projects, I have created one controller and one view (in their respective folders) and in the controller Index method I am passing list of products to View

```
Data.ProductRepository repository = new Data.ProductRepository();
var list = repository.GetProducts(1, true);
return View(list);
```

And the data is displayed correctly on the page. Now, I want to reformat the columns that are auto generated in the view (I used scaffold list tamplate). The problem is that no matter what I change into this view, the changes are not reflected on the page. I stop the web server, start again, always the same layout is displayed. Even removing columns from table doesn't work. It seems like it is using some cashed version of this page.

Thanks,
Goran

Comment: Are you rebuilding the project after you have made your changes? or just hitting F5?

Comment: Try to delete the view and then create another time

Comment: There seems to be inconsistency between DAL and database

Comment: @All

I have tried everything, building / rebuilding, and no success. Finally I have updated the VS, and it showed the new content, but only for the first time, after that I am  again in the same postition, changes are not applied to page.

Comment: Btw, I have also tried to recreate new project, and the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling both OS (XP) and IDE, it started working without any proeblems.